# Why is the [[]] operator subsetting faster than the [,] operator in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I benchmarked a few solutions for replacing missing values per column.

```
set.seed(11)
df <- data.frame(replicate(3, sample(c(1:5, -99), 6, rep = TRUE)))
names(df) <- letters[1:3]

fix_na <- function(x) {
  x[x == -99] <- NA
}

microbenchmark(
  for(i in seq_along(df)) df[, i] <- fix_na(df[, i]),
  for(i in seq_along(df)) df[[i]] <- fix_na(df[[i]]),
  df[] <- lapply(df, fix_na)
)

Unit: microseconds
                                                     expr     min       lq     mean      median   uq     max neval
 for (i in seq_along(df)) df[, i] <- fix_na(df[, i]) 179.167 191.9060 206.1650 204.2335 211.630 364.497   100
 for (i in seq_along(df)) df[[i]] <- fix_na(df[[i]])  83.420  92.8715 104.5787  98.0080 109.309 204.645   100
                          df[] <- lapply(df, fix_na) 105.199 113.4175 128.0265 117.9385 126.979 305.734   100
```

Why is the [[]] operator subsetting the dataframe 2x faster than the [,] operator?

EDIT

I included the two recommended calls from docendo discimus and increased the amount of data.

```
set.seed(11)
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(2000, sample(c(1:5, -99), 500, rep = TRUE)))
df2 <- df1
df3 <- df1
df4 <- df1
df5 <- df1
```

The results change yes, but my question still is there: [[]] performs faster than [,]

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                        expr       min        lq       mean        median      uq 
 for (i in seq_along(df1)) df1[, i] <- fix_na(df1[, i]) 301.06608 356.48011 377.31592 372.05625 392.73450 472.3330
 for (i in seq_along(df2)) df2[[i]] <- fix_na(df2[[i]]) 238.72005 287.55364 301.35651 298.05950 314.04369 386.4288
                           df3[] <- lapply(df3, fix_na) 170.53264 189.83858 198.32358 193.43300 202.43855 284.1164
                                 df4[df4 == -99] <- NA  75.05571  77.64787  85.59757  80.72697  85.16831  363.2223
                              is.na(df5) <- df5 == -99  74.44877  77.81799  84.22055  80.06496  83.01401  347.5798
```

Comment: If you are benchmarking on a small dataset, it doesn't give the correct output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Why is the \[\[ \]\] approach for subsetting a list faster than using $?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630087/r-why-is-the-approach-for-subsetting-a-list-faster-than-using)

Comment: You can add two more approaches to your benchmark: `df[df == -99] <- NA` and `is.na(df) <- df == -99`

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the hint. But as far as I know, the $ operator is short for [["x", exact = FALSE]]. So it does not really help in comparision with the [,] operator, or?

Comment: @Tobi_R. As I understand it has all got to do with partial matching theory (personally haven't had a chance to explore that deeply, this is hidden in the comments discussion). Also, `$` and `[[` are implemented using c functions,  Hadley has written a nice description on the different methods to subsetting http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html. Albeit the link doesn't have any benchmark results. Another good description on the performances of R is http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Arun. The second link gives an answer to a very similar question.

Comment: In your question you are _not_ comparing `[` VS `[[`. You _could_ be comparing `[.data.frame` VS `[[.data.frame` but you are actually, also, comparing `[<-.data.frame` VS `[[<-.data.frame`. You could scan through those functions and find what probably -if anything- adds computational time depending on the number of arguments etc.

Answer (score 0):

A faster approach would be using `set` from `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)
 for(j in seq_along(df)){
  set(df, i = which(df[[j]]== -99), j=j, value = NA)
 }
```

---

Regarding the OP's question about the benchmarking with `[` and `[[`, the `[[` extract the column without the overhead of `.data.frame`.  But, I would benchmark on a bigger dataset to find any difference.  Also, as we assign NA on the same data, it doesn't do any change when we are doing the operation again.

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(11)
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(2000, sample(c(1:5, -99), 500, rep = TRUE)))
df2 <- copy(df1)
df3 <- copy(df1)
df4 <- copy(df1)
df5 <- copy(df1)
df6  <- copy(df1)

 f1 <- function() for (i in seq_along(df1)) df1[, i] <- fix_na(df1[, i])
 f2 <- function() for (i in seq_along(df2)) df2[[i]] <- fix_na(df1[[i]])
 f3 <- function()  df3[] <- lapply(df3, fix_na)
 f4 <- function()  df4[df4 == -99] <- NA 
 f5 <- function()   is.na(df5) <- df5 == -99

 f6 <- function() {
   setDT(df6)
   for(j in seq_along(df)){
     set(df, i = which(df[[j]]== -99), j=j, value = NA)
   }  
  }

 t(sapply(paste0("f", 1:6), function(f) system.time(get(f)())))[,1:3]
 #   user.self sys.self elapsed
 #f1      0.29        0    0.30
 #f2      0.22        0    0.22
 #f3      0.11        0    0.11
 #f4      0.31        0    0.31
 #f5      0.31        0    0.32
 #f6      0.00        0    0.00
```

Here, I am using the `system.time` as the functions in the OP's post already replace the value of NA in the first run, so there is no point in running it again and again.

Comment: the OP ask why meth1 is faster than meth2 with a sample too small to conclude anyway. Your answer is "meth3 is faster" with a benchmark on meth3 in a decent sample. I don't find this answering the OP question. This is my opinion, you may disagree

Comment: **Moderator note**: Stop arguing over voting; if you want to discuss voting behaviour, either take it to Meta or chat.

Comment: Thank you for your faster solution akrun. I will keep it in mind. Why do you think that [ does opperate with the overhead of a data.frame? `Drop = True`, thus both results `df[, i]` and `df[[i]]` are vecors

Comment: @Tobi_R  The `[[` is used for subsetting a single column or a single list element.  By using `[`, it can be used for subsetting multiple columns and with `,`, the rows also comes into picture.  Though, we are making it blank on the lhs of `,`, I am guessing that it will still go check the row part.

Comment: `[[`, also, dispatches on its "data.frame" method and it, also, accepts argument for rows `mtcars[2, 6]` `mtcars[[2, 6]]`

Answer (score -1):

Got an answer for a very similar problem on the site suggested from Arun: adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html

At the section **Extracting a single value from a data frame** it says:

> Blockquote The following microbenchmark shows seven ways to access a single value (the number in the bottom-right corner) from the built-in mtcars dataset. The variation in performance is startling: the slowest method takes 30x longer than the fastest. **There’s no reason that there has to be such a huge difference in performance. It’s simply that no one has had the time to fix it.**

Among the different selection methods also the two operators [[ and [ are compared with the same results as observed by me. [[ outperforms [

Comment: Note that in your question you are not only _extracting_ values but, you're, also, _assigning_ values to "data.frame"

Comment: Well you are absolutly right. I did not see the _assigning_ part as a part of my stated problem. Thanks for pointing that out.